# PHP collecting filtered data from the second table of a HTML page

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I recently had a parsing problem quickly solved here but here is a new challenge I can't beat.

Here you have a (horrible) html page with multiple tables : [mxs link](http://mxsimulator.com/servers/mx.MXSConcept.com/)
The table that interest me is the second of the code, the one just under

`<DIV CLASS="main"><H3>funrace.MXSConcept.com</H3><H3>Recent Races</H3>`.

What I need is collecting all the races to obtain something like that in a dropdown box :

```
40 minutes ago - 8M+1L at 2013 Motosport World GP Rd 09: Lommel (2 riders)
1 day ago - 8M+1L at 2013 EMF FrenchCup Rd5 : Lacapelle Marival (1 riders)
...
as for exemple $date is the date,
$race is the second column,
$link is hidden but is the URL of the first column (to use later in my dropdown)
```

**ATTENTION :**
Dates seems to be generated on the fly with a js somes lines talk about a new track record --> these lines must be deleted.

Here is what I tried (hey stop laughing guys!) :

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

    $doc = new DOMDocument;
    //$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->loadHTMLfile('http://mxsimulator.com/servers/mx.MXSConcept.com/');
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $table = array();
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $table2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table')->item(1);

    // collect data
    $data = array();
    foreach ($table2->query('//tr') as $node) {
        $rowData = array();
        foreach ($table2->query('td', $node) as $cell) {
            $rowData[] = $cell->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    print_r($data);
```

Comment: What's the output with the code you have so far?

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::query() in /home/mxsconce/www/racing/results.php on line 56`
Nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, just ditch the `require('simple_html_dom.php');` since you're using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`.

Second, `$table2->query('//tr')` this will fail because its not a `DOMXpath` object. Its a `DOMElement`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://mxsimulator.com/servers/mx.MXSConcept.com/');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
// target each table row of the first table
$target_table_rows = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]/table[1]/tr');
// if there are rows found,
if($target_table_rows->length > 0) {
    // for each row, loop it
    foreach($target_table_rows as $row_key => $row) {
        // if the first td cell of this current row is empty
        if(trim($xpath->query('./td[1]', $row)->item(0)->nodeValue) == '') {
            continue; // then skip it
        }
        $data[] = array(
            'datetime' => $xpath->query('./td[1]', $row)->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $xpath->query('./td[1]/a', $row)->item(0)->getAttribute('href'),
            'description' => $xpath->query('./td[2]', $row)->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Output should look like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [datetime] => 2014-08-14 15:32 UTC
            [link] => /servers/mx.MXSConcept.com/races/825.html
            [description] => 8M+1L at 2013 Johnson Mine MX (1 riders)
        )
    ... and so on
```

Comment: Nice output there :)
Now, is there any rule to set that if the first td is empty (as I asked in my question) the line is ignored ?
I think it should be your `if` but I still got these lines

Comment: @Niko okay, i have skipped right thru it check the revision

Comment: That's on the right way. Now the empty cell is ignored as it should, but the second td of the tr is still there (telling about a track record). 
So when the cell is empty it's the entire row which has to be ignored.

Comment: @Niko you mean skip the entire row and don't put it inside the array if that first row td is empty? check the revision

Comment: This is it !
It works, woaw, syntax is really strange. Thank you for your skills Ghost.

Comment: Aaaaargh I (you ? :) ) forgot something !
I don't have the link in the array, the "href" tag.
I really need it.

Comment: @Niko you dont need a second foreach checkout my revision

Comment: I 100% agree with you about the second foreach, I just tried to do something working haha.
Your revision sounds good, I'll try it soon and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: Solution ok.
You rock.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use
 $doc->load(...)
for external files. There's a similar question answered here: [Xpath and conditionally selecting descendants based on element value of ancestors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866864/xpath-and-conditionally-selecting-descendants-based-on-element-value-of-ancestor)

Comment: Yes I tried but the specifications I need (second table, etc) makes it harder than the other posts I found, and I couldn't solve it myself. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update I did to have the link needed, but I'm sure there's an easier way. 
The goal is to have links in the same array, here I had to have a second one :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($selectserv);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $data = array();
    $links = array();
    // target each table row of the first table
    $target_table_rows = $xpath->query('//div[@class="main"]/table[1]/tr');
    // if there are rows found,
    if($target_table_rows->length > 0) {
        // for each row, loop it
        foreach($target_table_rows as $row_key => $row) {
            // if the first td cell of this current row is empty
            if(trim($xpath->query('./td[1]', $row)->item(0)->nodeValue) == '') {
                continue; // then skip it
            }
            // each td of this current row, push it inside the array data
            foreach($row->childNodes as $td) {
                $data[$row_key][] = $td->nodeValue;
            }

        }
        foreach($target_table_rows as $container) {
            $arr = $container->getElementsByTagName("a"); //get href tags
            foreach($arr as $item) {
              $href =  $item->getAttribute("href"); //get the href value I think ?
              $links[] = array(
                'href' => $href //put href in the array
              );
            }
        }
    }
```